# Cannot convert value of type 'Int.Type' to expected argument type 'Int' - Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-previews

What I am trying to do here is to move the value of "KarvonenVal" to SummaryView using NavigationLink.

```
struct CalcProcess: View{
    @EnvironmentObject var workoutManager: WorkoutManager

    @State var NumAdded4 = false
    @State var Age:Int
    @State var ExerciseIT:Int
    @State var ConstantNumber = 220
    @State var RHR:Int
    @State var KarvonenVal = 1
    
    
    func karvonen(cn: Int, rhr: Int, age: Int, ei:Double) -> Double {
        return Double((cn-age-rhr)) * (ei / 10) + Double(rhr)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        let output = karvonen(cn: ConstantNumber, rhr: RHR, age: Age, ei: Double(ExerciseIT))
        let roundedDouble = Double(round(1000*output)/1000)
        let KarvonenVal: String = String(format: "%.1f", roundedDouble)
           
        VStack{
            Text("\(KarvonenVal)")
                .foregroundStyle(.black)
        }
        NavigationLink(destination: SummaryView(NumAdded4: $NumAdded4, KarvonenVal: KarvonenVal), isActive: $NumAdded4, label: {Text("Next")})
        }
    }
}


struct KarvonenCalc_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        KarvonenCalc(KarvonenVal: Int)
    }
}
```

However, I kept receiving error at "KarvonenCalc_Previews" that says "Cannot convert value of type 'Int.Type' to expected argument type 'Int'". I am literally stuck here, and cannot display KarvonenVal at SummaryView.

```
struct KarvonenCalc_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        KarvonenCalc(KarvonenVal: Int)
    }
}
```

Also at SummaryView_Preview, I received the simillar error that says "Cannot convert value of type 'String.Type' to expected argument type 'String'".

```
struct SummaryView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SummaryView(NumAdded4: .constant(false), KarvonenVal: String)
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to supply an actual `Int` and `String`, for example `0` and `"hi"`.

Comment: i see. but then the KarvonenVal changes depending on input value.

Comment: A preview is just that, a preview so you can see how your UI will look like. So the value isn’t that relevant and it’s constant and not depending on any input.

Comment: Name your variables according to the naming convention with starting lowercase letter – as suggested in the answer to your previous question – and you will notice the issue instantly. You need a constant value rather than a  type. That is what the error says.

Comment: Off topic but start property and variable names with a lowercase letter and avoid using the same name for a local variable and a property, it makes the code harder to read and understand.

Comment: It is not an issue! You need to give an Int for preview! Off topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using variables/constants, it's a convention thing of having them lowercased. For types, they're uppercased.

So use 'karvonenVal' instead of 'KarvonenVal'. You are also using two properties with the same name:

```
let KarvonenVal: String = String(format: "%.1f", roundedDouble)
```

In the body and

```
@State var KarvonenVal = 1
```

right above as your struct property, so compiler is probably confused about which one to use and since they're both uppercased, it reads it as 'types' not as properties.

What you need to do is resolve name conflict between 'KarvonenVal'(rename one of them to something like 'KarvonenVal0' or whatever you like) and make all property names lowercased.

For preview you'll have to provide default values for it to work. It's basically asking you for some number that is an Integer and you're giving it the Integer Type. In other words it's asking for 'an object' and you're giving it 'a class'.